# Google Cloud - Load Balancing / No option for us-central1-b

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are testing out Google Cloud Compute Engine and just ran into an issue with the load balancing. All of our VM instances are in the zone us-central1-b and I just went in add another server into the load balancing and it now makes me select a zone for each VM instances but the only thing listed is us-central1-a so none of our VM instances are listed for us to select. It shows the region for the load balancing as us-central1 so how can we put the load balancing in -b so we can select the servers?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by going into Target Pools and creating a new pool and then it let me select us-central1-b